# android google map v2 disable names

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using custom TileProvider for my google Map v2. And I get tiles from the server. Here I have a problem. After adding new tiles, names are duplicated like on the picture below. Is it possible to disable names on standard google map v2?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't remove or disable labels from normal, terrain & hybrid map. So as far as I can see, you have 2 choices: use the sat view or create your own layers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Satellite view or Train view, it wont show names.